# OpenSSL - SSL Error : Too many open files

Tags: python, sqlite, oop

**what's wrong?**

Error message

```py
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_
from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'Too many open files'), ('BIO ro
utines', 'BIO_new_file', 'system lib'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load
_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]
```

- Store data locally using sqlite3 python
- I'm running it on a vps Ubuntu server
- 24 Hour Operation Time

Part of the storage code

```py
class orders :
    def __init__(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Orders (number_orders INTEGER)")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Orders")  
        entry = cursor.fetchall()   
        print(entry)
        if entry == []:
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('0')")
            
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    def add(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Orders SET number_orders=number_orders + '1' ")     
        
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()  
    def get(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()        
        cursor.execute("SELECT number_orders Orders from Orders") 
        num=cursor.fetchone()
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()  
        return num
```

> What's wrong? Is it the way the code was written or the in server?

> If there is any lack of information, please inform me.

Comment: It seems that your add function is no appropriate. It may throw exception and the connection will not be closed.

Comment: Is the fault of `connection.commit()` ?

Comment: ..............?

Comment: Use try catch and close the session in case of exception

Comment: Why do you think the exception happened?

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood. The syntax is ok but try catch is a good practice any way.

Comment: You're an Arab.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the obvious of closing a database connection or closing a file descriptor, you might legitimately get this error even when you are using Context Manager and properly closing open descriptors. Each running process in a unix/linux system defines the maximum file descriptors allowed per process. The `ulimit` command is used to set or retrieve various system limits for a process. When you are seeing an error like ‘too many open files’, you should indeed find out the maximum number of file descriptors allowed:

```
ulimit -n
```

If your application is running hundreds of threads and processing massive amounts of data, then you can indeed hit this limit. For example, if your application opens up 95,000 file descriptors among threads, then you might want to update the ulimit on your OS. In Linux, you can make the change in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. So you can update the file as so:

```
* soft nofile 500000
* hard nofile 500000

# End of file
```

This change will apply permanently as opposed to only changing the current shell. Reboot the OS and verify the change took effect with ulimit -n.

This additional debugging you can do in the Python code itself to determine if indeed the ulimit value for max file descriptors is the issue. In a running Python application, find out the max file descriptors:

```
import os

fd_limit = os.sysconf('SC_OPEN_MAX’)
print(fd_limit)
```

In your Python application, you can also invoke num_fds() of the process to determine how many file descriptors are opened as it is running:

```
import os
import psutil

pid = os.getpid()
active_process = psutil.Process(pid)
print(f'Current file descriptor count: {active_process.num_fds()}’)
```